# Time series index elasticsearch range date query url

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I have a time series indexed like the following pattern "index-%{YYYY-MM-dd}".

I know that it's possible to make a query by "date" directly in the url:

```
GET /%3Cindex-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D%3E/_search
```

Is it possible to make a query url by date range ? In the elasticsearch example, they join 3 index pattern to make a query for the last 3 days (for instance).

```
GET /<logstash-{now/d-2d}>,<logstash-{now/d-1d}>,<logstash-{now/d}>/_search
```

Is there any way to make an url query by date range, to focus my search for performance matter ?

Comment: guess this question didn't gather enough attention. did you find a way to achieve what you wanted?